# 2 minutes interval ping in Linux

Tags: linux, networking, ping

I want to ping 192.168.1.254 every 2 minutes. Tried the following but it doesn't seem to ping again in 2 minutes.

*ping -i 360 192.168.1.254*

How can I get the ping to work every 2 minutes? 
Is there anything I need to check/enable in embedded Linux? 
I am using teraterm, is there a need to write a Macro to make it work?

[**EDIT**]: I just realised that 360 is 6 minutes. But yeah basically it still doesn't ping again after 6 minutes.

I think the issue here is because it's an embedded linux, normal ping works fine. I am not sure how I can go about and enable the -i option.

Comment: 360 = 60 * 6 = 6 minutes. Maybe try 120 for 2 minutes? If your version of `ping` doesn't support `-i`, try a shell-script loop and `sleep`.

Comment: **interval** after `-i` is in seconds. So, you just need to **replace 360 to 120`** as 120 seconds = 2 mins. Also, make sure that plain ping is working in the first place.

Comment: can someone asnwer down so that it can be closed ? preferably @dirkt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

360 = 60 * 6 = 6 minutes. Maybe try 120 for 2 minutes?

If your version of ping doesn't support `-i`, try a shell-script loop and `sleep`:

```
while true ; do ping -c1 192.168.1.254 ; sleep 120 ; done
```

If your version of ping neither supports `-i` nor `-c`, find out what options it *does* support, and edit question with that info.